# How to join 2 tables and have a list of other table's values nested in the first one in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relationship

Let's assume that we have these 2 tables: **person and car**

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE car (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    make VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    person_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES person(id)
);
```

What I try to do is to find all people, find every car and create an array of objects like this one

```json
[
    {
        "id": "PERSON_ID",
        "name": "PERSON_NAME",
        "cars": [
            {
                "id": "CAR_ID",
                "model": "MODEL_NAME",
                "person_id": "PERSON_ID"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have tried using the `AS` alias with a `JOIN` on `person` table from `car` table but it didn't work. Is there a way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following. See a working fiddle:

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE car (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    make VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    person_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES person(id)
);

insert into person(name) values ('tom'),('harry');

insert into car (id,make,person_id) values (1,'ford',1),(2,'audi',1),(3,'nissan',2);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
   p.id,
   p.name,
   array_agg(row_to_json(c)) cars
FROM
   person p
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT id, make model, person_id FROM car) c ON p.id = c.person_id
GROUP BY
   p.id,
   p.name;
```

| id | name | cars |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tom | [{"id":1,"model":"ford","person_id":1},{"id":2,"model":"audi","person_id":1}] |
| 2 | harry | [{"id":3,"model":"nissan","person_id":2}] |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5izpFv5YVUD2gKYgCDGgsu/0)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! It works correctly! By the way, if you don't mind can you please give me such example but for just one object? Like a column has another column but only one. Not an array. I am a beginner and just finished a 4 hour course. Just trying to get my hands dirty with it. Cheers!

Comment: Could you clarify further in another question? What do you mean that a column has another column? does one object mean one row?

Comment: Sure, I want to achieve something like this: https://pastebin.com/cpmaYgV6

Comment: @xyz1888 have a look at this fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5izpFv5YVUD2gKYgCDGgsu/1

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result set as an *array* in Postgres, you can use:

```
select p.*, array_agg(c)
from person p join
     car c
     on c.person_id = p.id
group by p.id;
```

You can do something similar if you want JSON returned as well.

Comment: I had tried the `array_agg(c)` also but the sample results generated `{"(1,ford,1)","(2,audi,1)"}` a seeming array of string tuples. See fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=df814b6320c1d086d5d5bfd8f4180655

Comment: @ggordon . . . Those are not really strings.  That is just how Postgres is representing the record value.  You can still access the elements and fields:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9f355eb04db29064093d0f4162b7b0b1

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Works as intended! If I could, I'd have upvoted this answer and @ggordon 's answer.

Comment: Thanks for this @GordonLinoff. This has been enlightening